# renv and git interaction R

Tags: r, git, version-control, environment, renv

I am trying to get better understanding how `renv` package in R works and how it interacts with git. Here are my questions

1. Assume I have master and a couple git branches in my R projects for each (master and branches) I would like to use different environments (different libraries or different versions of the same libraries). Would `renv` be able to handle it, i.e. if I switch from one branch to another will need to call `renv::restore()`.
2. I have two separate projects with `renv` running in both of them, call them project A and project B. I would like to take environment from project B and replace environment in project A. How can I accomplish it? Do I just need to copy `renv` folder from one project to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Assume I have master and a couple git branches in my R projects for each (master and branches) I would like to use different environments (different libraries or different versions of the same libraries). Would renv be able to handle it, i.e. if I switch from one branch to another will need to call renv::restore().

`renv` excludes the project library from version control (to avoid bloating the repository size), so in normally you would be required to restore the library path when switching branches.

This is a bit arduous, so another solution would be to configure `renv` to use a different library path for each branch for your `git` repository. You could accomplish this with something like (in your project `.Rprofile`):

```
branch <- system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD", intern = TRUE)
Sys.setenv(RENV_PATHS_LIBRARY = file.path("renv/library/branches", branch))
```

This way, `renv` would be automatically configured to use a separate library for each branch, and this would happen automatically as you switch branches.

This seems like something that would be useful to have in general; you might consider filing a feature request at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues if so.

> I have two separate projects with renv running in both of them, call them project A and project B. I would like to take environment from project B and replace environment in project A. How can I accomplish it? Do I just need to copy renv folder from one project to another?

That should suffice, although it depends on how much of the environment you want to copy. The `renv` folder contains a `settings.dcf` file, defining project settings -- you may or may not want to copy those settings over as well. (See `?renv::settings` for documention on `renv`'s project-specific settings.)

Alternatively, you could copy the project `renv.lock` from project B to project A, and then call `renv::restore()`. This might be more appropriate if you were e.g. copying a project from one machine to another, especially if those machines were running on different operating systems.